# How to avoid Docker data clutter during rapid development cycles

Tags: docker

I am developing a dockerized application. From time to time I rebuild and run the image/container on my machine to do some testing. To do so I naively executed the following:

```
docker image build -t myapp .
docker container run -p 8020:5000 -v $(pwd)/data:/data myapp
```

This seems to work quite well. But today I realized that the docker folder on my machine has grown quite big in the last three weeks (> 200 GB).

So it seems that all the supposedly temporary containers, images, volumes etc. have piled up on my disk.

What would be the right way to solve this? I only need one version of my image, so it would be great everything was simply overwritten every time I start a new test cycle.

Alternatively I could execute a `docker system prune`, but that seems overkill.

Comment: you could filter out images, that are older then X: `docker [container|image] prune --filter "until=24h"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Majority of space is occupied by images and volumes so pruning only them would be better option  then `docker system prune`.

```
docker image prune
docker volume prune
```

image prune will clean all dangling images that were untagged from myapp due to a new image built and tag to myapp.

Also as the containers are started for testing/dev, they can be started with `--rm` for cleaning when stopped.